# how to find out in which class i currently include my module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how do we find out in which class we are currently including a module? (coming from rails-background where we do the has_* style modules)

```
class Foo
  has_likes
end

module HasLikes
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def has_likes(options = {})
    end
  end

  module ContentMethods
    def self.included(base)
      base.extend ClassMethods
    end


    #  ?????
    # how do we get Foo here?

  end
end
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Generally speaking a module shouldn't need to know what it's been included in, and if it does it's probably an indication that you need to rethink your design.

Comment: @Jordan the *has_likes* has types of likes (love, wow, sad). it should generate also methods `foo.love_likes`, `foo.wow_likes`. this ain't a problem, because the types are pre-defined in the has_likes anyways, BUT, our models can limit them. a Comment can only receive `like_like`and not other type, so i thought that they then also don't need the `wow_likes`or `sad_likes`

Comment: If the model can limit them, than that code should be in the model, e.g. `has_likes only: [:wow, :love]`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @Jordan said in comments, it smells as a design flaw.

Secondary, inside `ContentMethods` *declaration*, it’s definitely impossible, since it is always included *after* been declared.

In general, one might do it afterwards with [`ObjectSpace#each_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object):

```
module HasLikes
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def has_likes(options = {})
    end
  end

  module ContentMethods
    def self.included(base)
      base.extend ClassMethods
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include ::HasLikes::ContentMethods
  has_likes
end

ObjectSpace.each_object(Class) do |x|
  p(x) if x <= ::HasLikes::ContentMethods
end
#⇒ Foo
```

But please do not do that at home or school.

Comment: school? haha

the *has_likes* has types of likes (love, wow, sad). it should generate also methods `foo.love_likes`, `foo.wow_likes`. this ain't a problem, because the types are pre-defined in the has_likes anyways, BUT, our models can limit them. a Comment can only receive `like_like`and not other type, so i thought that they then also don't need the `wow_likes`or `sad_likes`

Comment: This is the different task. Do the whole job inside `self.included` with [`included.send :define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Module.html#method-i-define_method), there you have `base` and hence an ability to decide, what to declare explicitly. Or, even better, pass the methods to declare as parameter to `has_likes`, like `has_likes allowed: %i|sad_likes wow_likes|`.